# Why I get "Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'" error?

Tags: c#

```
int UserA;

Console.WriteLine("What is 5 + 5");
UserA = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
if(UserA == 10) {
    Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
} else if(UserA == 9 || 11 ) {

}
```

Why am I not able to use the `OR` operand here. I know its simple but I am quite stuck.

Comment: You can't daisy chain conditional statements, you need to define them.

Comment: `UserA == 9` evaulates to a boolean (true or false). You can't OR a boolean with a number. (11)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It supposed to be:

```
UserA == 9 || UserA == 11
```

Comment: very impressive